# Elegant way to validate values

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have a class with many fields which represents different physical values.

```
class Tunnel
{
    private double _length;
    private double _crossSectionArea;
    private double _airDensity;
    //...
```

Each field is exposed using read/write property. I need to check on setter that the value is correct and generate exception otherwise. All validations are similar:

```
    public double Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value",
                    "Length must be positive value.");
            _length = value;
        }
    }

    public double CrossSectionArea
    {
        get { return _crossSectionArea; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value",
                    "Cross-section area must be positive value.");
            _crossSectionArea = value;
        }
    }

    public double AirDensity
    {
        get { return _airDensity; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value",
                    "Air density can't be negative value.");
            _airDensity = value;
        }
    }
    //...
```

Is there any elegant and flexible way to accomplish such validation?

Comment: I think the way you've done it is the correct way to go. The only change would be maybe create a `validator function` that you call whenever you are ready that checks *all* of your values at one time. In my experience, Visual Studio (don't know what you are using) seems to swallow exceptions that occur in a property setter.

Comment: @jp2code, exceptions in setter works fine. Just checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want this sort of behaviour, you might consider some helper methods, e.g.

```
public static double ValidatePositive(double input, string name)
{
    if (input <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name + " must be positive");
    }
    return input;
}

public static double ValidateNonNegative(double input, string name)
{
    if (input < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name + " must not be negative");
    }
    return input;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
public double AirDensity
{
    get { return _airDensity; }
    set
    {            
        _airDensity = ValidationHelpers.ValidateNonNegative(value,
                                                            "Air density");
    }
}
```

If you need this for various types, you could even make it generic:

```
public static T ValidateNonNegative(T input, string name)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (input.CompareTo(default(T)) < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(name + " must not be negative");
    }
    return input;
}
```

Note that none of this is terribly i18n-friendly...

Comment: Thanks for improving code. But I hasn't understood what you mean about "i18n-friendly"...

Comment: @archer: The messages are hard-coded as English. You'll have a bit more work ahead of you if you want to translate them into a different language.

Comment: RATS! I like this one much better than the little validator routine I just wrote. I even invoked Thy name! :)

Answer (score 4):

All depends what technology you are using - if you're under MVC you can use Attributes, like this;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Neither was I - the MVC attributes handle both client side and server side validation (see the Model.IsValid method)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my version, it's a bit cleaner than Jon's version in some respects:

```
interface IValidator <T>
{
  bool Validate (T value);
}

class IntValidator : IValidator <int>
{
  public bool Validate (int value)
  {
    return value > 10 && value < 15;
  }
}
class Int2Validator : IValidator<int>
{
  public bool Validate (int value)
  {
    return value > 100 && value < 150;
  }
}

struct Property<T, P> where P : IValidator<T>, new ()
{
  public T Value
  {
    set
    {
      if (m_validator.Validate (value))
      {
        m_value = value;
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Error validating: '" + value + "' is out of range.");
      }
    }

    get { return m_value; }
  }

  T m_value;
  static IValidator<T> m_validator=new P();
}

class Program
{
  static void Main (string [] args)
  {
    Program
      p = new Program ();

    p.m_p1.Value = 9;
    p.m_p1.Value = 12;
    p.m_p1.Value = 25;
    p.m_p2.Value = 90;
    p.m_p2.Value = 120;
    p.m_p2.Value = 250;
  }

  Property<int, IntValidator>
    m_p1;

  Property<int, Int2Validator>
    m_p2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use such a method:

```
 public void FailOrProceed(Func<bool> validationFunction, Action proceedFunction, string errorMessage)
    {
        // !!! check for nulls, etc
        if (!validationFunction())
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(errorMessage);
        }

        proceedFunction();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using classes from [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

```
class Tunnel
{
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Length must be positive value.")]
    public double Length { get; set; }
}
```

Validation:

```
var tunnel = new Tunnel { Length = 0 };
var context = new ValidationContext(tunnel, null, null);
Validator.ValidateObject(tunnel, context, true);
```

Also you can implement your own validation attributes overriding [`ValidationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) class

Comment: This seems like it's going to introduce a bit of overhead surely?

Comment: @Skizz, It is validation using attributes, no more. I don't like implement validation inside `set` accessor.

Comment: what I was getting at was the run time connection between the property and the attribute. Maybe .net does something clever here.

Comment: @Skizz, It depends on task, but many .NET frameworks such Entity Framework, WPF, ASP.NET MVC, etc use reflection. This validation is something like simple AOP version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by creating your own validation attributes.

Read this article: [Business Object Validation Using Attributes in C#](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Business-Object-Validation-Using-Attributes-in-C.aspx)

I will have the decency of NOT copying it here `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the Validator function I mentioned in my comment above, I'd do something like this (untested code):

```
void textBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  submitButton.Enabled = validator();
}

bool validator() {
  const string NON_POSITIVE = "Value must be greater than Zero";
  bool result = false;
  string controlName = "Length";
  try {
    _length = Convert.ToDouble(txtLength.Text);
    if (_length <= 0) throw new Exception(NON_POSITIVE);
    controlName = "Cross Section Area";
    _crossSectionArea = Convert.ToDouble(txtCrossSectionArea.Text);
    if (_crossSectionArea <= 0) throw new Exception(NON_POSITIVE);
    controlName = "Air Density";
    _airDensity = Convert.ToDouble(txtAirDensity.Text);
    if (_airDensity <= 0) throw new Exception(NON_POSITIVE);
    result = true; // only do this step last
  } catch (Exception err) {
    MessageBox.Show(controlName + " Error: " + err.Message, "Input Error");
  }
  return result;
}
```

John Skeet probably has a better way, but this works. :)